# Drupal, node clone link in view fields

Tags: drupal

I'm trying to create a node clone link in a view,

I install the module `node clode` and added the view field, but the td is empty (i.e. no link display)

When I trace with debugger I reached the following code:

```
function clone_is_permitted($type) {
  $omitted = variable_get('clone_omitted', array());
  return empty($omitted[$type]);
}
```

which is called with the value `req_positions` (this is the content type)

```
$omitted = {array} [23]
 simplenews = "simplenews"
 advertise = "advertise"
 icons = "icons"
 req_positions = "req_positions"
 message = "message"
 volunteer = "volunteer"
 webform = "webform"
 form_jobs = "form_jobs"
 article = "article"
 info_to_event = "info_to_event"
 location = "location"
 recipe = "recipe"
 recommended_books = "recommended_books"
 newsletter = "newsletter"
 simple_page = "simple_page"
 post = "post"
 prptocol = "prptocol"
 link = "link"
 faq = "faq"
 content_presentation = "content_presentation"
 donation = "donation"
 event = 0
 podcast = 0
```

I would like to remove the req_positions from clone_omitted.

What is the proper way do to this?

Answer (score 0):

This value can be set in /admin/config/content/clone